# Arreglos de cadenas

Tags: array, c

¿Cómo puedo guardar cadenas en un arreglo en C?
Por ejemplo quiero un arreglo donde pueda guardar 3 nombres

arreglo  = "juan", "Pedro" , "Santiago";

juan en la posición 0 del arreglo
Pedro en la posición 1 del arreglo
Santiago en la posición 2 del arreglo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define un array de la siguiente forma

```
char *arreglo[]={"Juan","Pedro","Santiago"};
```

es un arreglo de punteros a Strings. Para imprimir el contenido de cada elemento del array deberas hacer, por ejempo:

```
printf("Es %s", *arreglo[0]); //Es Juan
printf("Es %s", *arreglo[1]); //Es Pedro
printf("Es %s", *arreglo[2]); //Es Santiago
```

Si pones solo:

```
arreglo[0];
```

te mostrara la dirección de memoria donde esta alojado el puntero a dicha cadena, valor el cual, supongo, no te interesa.

Comment: Como imprimo uno de los elementos de ese arreglo, por ejemplo "Pedro"? @Franco Rolando

Comment: @Fr13nds ahi edite la respuesta.

Comment: ya me sirvió, muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Hola posibilidad es utilizar un arreglo de estructuras, donde la estructura, a su vez, tenga un campo que sea un arreglo, en este caso el campo "nombre".

Esta solución es apropiada si existirán otros datos asociados a la persona, como DNI o teléfono. Esos datos serán nuevos campos de la estructura persona_s

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Crea el tipo de dato "persona_s"
struct persona_s
{
    char nombre[30] ;
};

int main()
{
    //Crea la estructura de tipo persona    
    struct persona_s arreglo[3];

    //Escribe el campo nombre con los valores desados
    strcpy (arreglo[0].nombre, "Juan");
    strcpy (arreglo[1].nombre, "Pedro");
    strcpy (arreglo[2].nombre, "Santiago");

    //Imprime el contenido del campo nombre
    for (int i = 0 ; i<3 ; i++)
    {
        printf("Nombre: %s\n",arreglo[i].nombre);
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```